# How long does System.in.read() blocks in Java

Tags: java, system.in

`System.in` is a [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html) in Java.

The api for the [`read()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) says

> This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the
>   stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.

```
 try {
   int inByte = System.in.read();
   System.out.println("Typed char: " + (char) inByte);
 } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

So now, I try to run this program above and it lets me type in many many characters and only stops blocking if I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on my keyboard.

Aren't there enough data available (how the api writes) when I only hit one key (that is one byte, e.g. `A` in `UTF-8`) and the program could continue afterwards?

The `read(byte[])` behaves the same.. It blocks till the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>.